# react router double nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="signin" component={skipWhenAuthHoc(SignIn)} />
    <Route path="signup" component={skipWhenAuthHoc(SignUp)} />
    <Route path="signout" component={SignOut} />
    <Redirect from="account" to="/account/profile" />
    <Route path="account">
      <Route path="profile" component={UserProfile} />
      <Route path="setting" component={UserSetting} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

i have my router set up like this, the url for the 1st level routes works (signin signup, signout).

However,  i refresh the browser with url 'localhost:8080/account/profile', the broswer will give `404` error for `GET http://localhost:8080/account/bundle.js`.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to modify your routes component if your intention is route user to /account/profile when user browse /account.

```
<Router history={history}>
 <Route path="/" component={App}>
 <IndexRoute component={Home} />
 <Route path="signin" component={skipWhenAuthHoc(SignIn)} />
 <Route path="signup" component={skipWhenAuthHoc(SignUp)} />
 <Route path="signout" component={SignOut} />
 <Route path="account">
   <IndexRoute path="profile" component={UserProfile} />
   <Route path="setting" component={UserSetting} />
</Route>
```

Comment: /account/bundle.js is not found, when i refresh the browser